# iPhone / iPad Console?

Tags: ios, console

I want to see what happens in the device if I'm  testing the app.

For example if I open a link in safari, see it what happens in the console or if I install a web-app see the links that I'm pressing in console.

How can I do this?

I want to see it  terminal, or if there are other software, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has a built in console that will show you what is going on in your simulator.